# Custom SQL Query using select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, regex, linq

Hey all I am trying to make a friendly UI to create a MS SQL query string. So far I have the following code for the **SELECT** part of the dropbox box:

```
//Logic for SELECT
$.each(_tmpSELECT, function (index, item) {
   if (item == "AS") {
       catchAS = true;
   } else if (catchAS) {
       //Get AS "zzzzz"
       catchAS = false;
       _SelectQuery = _SelectQuery.replace(/(^\s*,)|(,\s*$)/g, '');
       _SelectQuery += " AS " + item + ", ";
   } else if (item == "SUM") {
       catchSUM = true;
   } else if (catchSUM) {
       //Get SUM("zzzzz")
       catchSUM = false;
       _SelectQuery += "SUM(" + item + "), ";
   } else if (item == "DISTINCT") {
       catchDISTINCT = true;
   } else if (catchDISTINCT) {
       //Get DISTINCT "zzzzz"
       catchDISTINCT = false;
       _SelectQuery += "DISTINCT " + item + ", ";
   } else if (item == "TOP") {
       catchTOP = true;
   } else if (catchTOP) {
       //Get TOP NNNN
       catchTOP = false;
       _SelectQuery += "TOP " + item + ", ";
   } else {
       _SelectQuery += item + ", ";
   }
 });

//Clean up...
SelectQuery = _SelectQuery.replace(/(^\s*,)|(,\s*$)/g, '');
```

Which does work just fine... but the problem is, this is only the **SELECT** part of the query and I still have the **WHERE** & **AND** parts to go which are much more complicated since it has more operators to check for.

I was wondering if anyone has already done something like this before and would be willing to share their code.... **or** know of a simpler way of doing this via **REGEX** or something simular (LINQ, etc etc) using **javascript** or **jQuery**?

Thanks!

Comment: SQL syntax is no way regular.

Comment: @hjpotter92 That's not really a helpful comment...

Comment: I'm not sure to fully understand what you are trying to do. But it seems some kind of automated query builder. I did this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlapi ...maybe it could be useful for you.